# Time travel book for young adults, available in school libraries in 70s, cape-wearing girl meets Greensleeves-whistling boy

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, young-adult

Tyring to identify a 70s book about a teenaged girl in England, alone at boarding school over the holidays, who puts on a cape from the school theatre and time travels.  She meets a boy in the woods from another era (Tudor?) who is whistling Greensleeves.  He's involved in a plot of some sort.  This is not Allison Uttley's book.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Time Tangle by Frances Eagar. 1976/7. The boy who sings "Greensleeves" is called Adam.

Cover:
http://www.librarything.com/work/361104

"While staying at her convent school over Christmas, a young girl meets a mysterious young man she believes is a ghost from the sixteenth century."